# Questions regarding best use of testng and mockito

Tags: spring, testng, mockito

I am very new for testng(unit testing) and mockito. I have read some articles and went through some code snippets on Internet. But still I have some doubts regarding unit testing with `testng` & `mockito` in `spring framework`.

1. For unit testing a service layer we mock a DAO. What if I want to test a function wich fetch some data from database and do some operations. How does mock DAO works here. From where mocked DAO will get some data for testing such a function.
2. If am doing a validation like Data not present in database and I want to test wheather it throws correct exception for that. So it needs some values in database and mocked DAO will check if data present in that predefined database(in-memory). How to provide such a data.
3. Does dataprovider helps to provide a data to used by DAO. If yes, How it can be done?

Please correct me if my understanding regarding unit testing is correct. Please let me know where I am getting it wrong if I miss understood a concept.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Besides UnitTests, you also need Integration and / or Acceptance-Tests. 
The Unit-Tests will test that your SUT - Single Unit of Test, in this case a specific service class works as intended, without integrating it with other classes or systems (DB). However, additionally I would write an Integration Test for this Service that retrieves / manipulates test data from the database. This test should ideally not make any assumptions about the data in the database, so inserting the data you will be looking for, before executing the test, is recommended, e.g. using a @Before annotation and actually committing this test data into the test database. However, I further recommend you to do a proper cleanup of the database, in the @After test method. Auto rolling back the data could be done, but is not as optimal, especially if you have a persistence framework like Hibernate or JPA in between. Only when you work on committed data that is really in the physical (not virtual!) dabase, you can be 100% sure your test succeeded.

2. If I correctly understood your intend, this actually sounds like a perfect reason for mocking your DB / persistence object - make it throw the expected exception / return an empty result, that test that your code behaves as expected on this condition.
3. A TestNG Dataprovider actually does the opposite of what you are looking for - it is a way to provide an array of data to your test method:
   `org.testng.annotations.DataProvider`
   Annotation Type DataProvider
   Mark a method as supplying data for a test method. The data provider name defaults to method name. The annotated method must return an Object[][] where each Object[] can be assigned the parameter list of the test method. The @Test method that wants to **receive** data from this DataProvider needs to use a dataProvider name equals to the name of this annotation.